# Disable input box until anchor link clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm trying to set the input text box of my app to disabled until a username is clicked from the right side. I've tried using `ng-disabled` on the input box, but can't set it to disabled until a link is clicked.

I think the username in the users list need to have a model set to check for state, but that doesn't seem to have worked.

**users list directive**

```
chatApp.directive("usersList", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: false,
    template: "<p>Users</p>"+
        "<ol class='list-unstyled animated fadeInDown'>"+
          "<li ng-repeat='user in users'>"+
            "<a class='users' ng-click='toggleDetails(message)'>{{user.name | uppercase}}</a>"+
          "</li>"+
        "</ol>"
    ,
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.toggleDetails = function(message)
      {
        angular.forEach(scope.messages, function(value, key){
          if(message != value)
            value.showDetails = false;
        });
        message.showDetails =  !message.showDetails;
      }
    }
}
});
```

**The messages directive with text input that needs to be disabled until user clicks link from users directive**

```
chatApp.directive("messagesList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: false,
        template: "<div class='panel panel-primary'>"+
            "<div class='panel-heading'>"+
                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></span> Chat</div>"+
                "<div class='panel-body body-panel'>"+
                  "<ol class='list-unstyled'>"+
                    "<li ng-repeat='message in messages | filter:{showDetails:true}'>"+
                        "<p>{{message.user | uppercase}}: {{message.message}}</p>"+
                        "<p>Matt: {{response}}</p>"+
                        "<span ng-repeat='message in messages | filter:{showDetails:true}'>{{message.user | uppercase}}:</span>{{autoresponse}}"+
                    "</li>"+
                  "</ol>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='panel-footer clearfix'>"+
                  "<form name='form'>"+
                    "<input type='text' name='message' ng-model='chat' class='form-control' />"+
                    "<span class='col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12' style='margin-top: 10px'>"+
                        "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block' id='btn-chat' ng-click='sendMessage(messages)' ng-disabled='!form.message.$dirty'>Send</button>"+
                    "</span>"+
                  "</form>"+
                "</div>"+
        "</div>"
        };
});
```

**Current plunker: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ds19G06w8oQ4maM4Kiud?p=preview)**

Comment: The UI gives no guidance that a username needs to be selected. To create a better user experience, consider using [ng-show and ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to guide the user and only reveal the input when the user has completed the required step.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable in your controller that denotes whether one of the links has been clicked:

```
chatApp.controller("chatController",function($scope, $timeout, $firebaseArray)
{
   $scope.userSelected = false;
   //...
}
```

When you click on one of the links, you set this to `true` inside the `usersList` directive.

```
link: function(scope) {
   scope.toggleDetails = function(message)
   {
        scope.userSelected = true;
        // ...
   }
```

Finally, like you said, your `input` should have an `ng-disabled` attribute:

```
<input ng-disabled='!userSelected' />
```

This works but it leaves me wondering when the input should be disabled again...

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The only issue is that clicking the same name again will hide the content of the chat window.

Comment: To add to this answer, I would use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) `$scope.userSelected = $scope.messages.some(function(user){return user.showDetails;});`